# Insert space after .com .net . org etc. (all domain name extensions) with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is it possible? Some users put a dot or a comma after their domain name while commenting on my site and the links don't open like they should. I need to put a space right after the domain name extensions using preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to add a space after the domain extension :

```
$x=" .com, .net.org";

echo preg_replace("/\.(com|net|org)/i","$1 ",$x);
```

Demo : https://eval.in/533412

Comment: I like that, I can then manually add a list of all know domain name extensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but there is already a parse_url method for that.
http://docs.php.net/parse_url

Anyway the matching regex would be something like this:

```
(www\..*\..{2,3})*
```